# Share a photo to facebook from e-mail

Tags: c#, facebook, email, share, photo

My application (C# winforms) constructs an email and sends it to a customer. To the email there is a photo attached. 
What i want to do, is to add a facebook share button into the e-mail so the user can share the attached photo on facebook by clicking this share button.

I already managed to construct the e-mail with the photo attached. I manage also to add a facebook share button to e-mail, but i cannot figure out how the attached photo can be uploaded and shared on facebook through a single url.

The url (which is attached to the share button) i came up with, which is pretty close to what i want:

href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u= 
'img src="http://www.somesite.com/apicture.jpg" />

but this requires the photo to be uploaded to somesite.com before this will work, and that's not what i want.

Any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to share an image then you must have a url of it, you can't share by uploading.

You can first upload the image to facebook (for example) but you won't be able to do that from withing the email, and the user will have to authenticate in order to do that, and so you won't be able to do that from where you send the mail (if I understand the scenario right).

What you should do is to have the image on the server where you send the mail from (or another server in your disposal), and then use that url with the share button.

Another thing that you should take into account is that the share button has been deprecated and is no longer supported by facebook, as it says [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/):

> The Share button has been deprecated in favor of the Like button, and
>   will no longer be supported. Please use the Like button whenever
>   possible to drive maximum traffic to your apps.

And [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/):

> **What happened to the old Share button?**
>
> We deprecated the Share Button when we launched the Like button,
>   because the Like button improves clickthrough rates by allowing users
>   to connect with one click, and by allowing them to see which of their
>   friends have already connected.

In your specific case it will be problematic to use the like button since it requires the facebook js sdk which can not be attached to an email.

Comment: Ok Nitzan, thanks for your answer! Yes you understood the scenario. I already was a bit afraid that i needed some server to point the image to get a vaild url. I'll look into that now. Thx again!